# How do I stop server side event getting called

Tags: javascript

I have made a method for adding an image to the page for user feedback. I have tried the method on its own and now want to use it over and over again so it matches the validation on the site.

```
function ValidateFields(div, imgDiv) {
var validPass = true;

var elem = document.getElementById(div).value;
if (elem == "") {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "/assets/img/errorIcon.png";
    var src = document.getElementById(imgDiv);
    src.appendChild(img);
    validPass = false;
    //document.getElementById('lbl_pdf_title').innerText = ("Please enter a title for the PDF");
}
return (validPass);
}
```

When I used this method by passing in the correct values it works ok, but now I want to use the method like this:

```
function ValidatePdf() {
ValidateFields('txt_pdf_title', 'imgPdfError');

   if (!ValidateFields()) {
      // make it false
    }
}
```

I want to use the method lots of times in the `ValidatePdf()` but it shows the symbol then carries on to run the serverside method.
This is my button click:

```
<button id="btn_submit_pdf"
                runat="server"
                class="btn btn-default"
                title="Submit PDF"
                onclick="if (!ValidatePdf()) return false;"
                onserverclick="btn_submit_pdf_Click">
                Submit
            </button>
```

Do I need to pass another value to the `ValidateFields()` 
I am at a loss as why it doesn't work.But does when you pass the original values in and call the method on the button click

Comment: why are you calling `ValidateFields()` with no args?  Also, `var elem = document.getElementById(div).value;` is problematic if the element doesn't exist. Did you check your console for errors?

Comment: Which server side technology are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return the result of `ValidateFields`:

```
function ValidatePdf() {
    return ValidateFields('txt_pdf_title', 'imgPdfError');
}
```

You can also change your `onclick` to:

```
onclick="return ValidatePdf();"
```

so that it returns the result of `ValidatePdf`, which is now the result of `ValidateFields`.

Comment: Beat me by just a few seconds, with a more efficient solution, and additional help. +1.

Comment: I think it is not the right answer: The OP wants to validate multiple fields and with this code it is not possible.

Comment: If OP wants to validate multiple fields, then OP should do so in the `ValidateFields` method. This solution answers the question of why his `onclick` isn't working to block the call to OP's server-side function. Also, OP hasn't posted any actual fields to validate, so your guess as to what needs to be validated is as good as mine.

Comment: I just trying to understand what the OP means by "lots of times". No need to get pissed.

Comment: Validating more empty fields

Comment: @JanHommes: I'm not upset, merely validating my answer.

Comment: @StudentRik: What do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

For multiplie validation you just need to add another boolean value:

```
function ValidatePdf() {
  var isValidate=true;
  isValidate=isValidate && ValidateFields('txt_pdf_title', 'imgPdfError');
  isValidate=isValidate && ValidateFields('txt_pdf_title1', 'imgPdfError1');
  isValidate=isValidate && ValidateFields('txt_pdf_title2', 'imgPdfError2');
  return(isValidate);
}
```

Or

```
function ValidatePdf() {
  return(ValidateFields('txt_pdf_title', 'imgPdfError') && ValidateFields('txt_pdf_title1', 'imgPdfError1') && ValidateFields('txt_pdf_title2', 'imgPdfError2'));
}
```

Comment: This would overwrite the value of `isValidate` on every call. If the first returned `false`, and the third returned `true`, `ValidatePdf` would return `true`. You should `&&` the results together to return the correct result of the validation: `isValidate = isValidate && ValidateFields('txt_pdf_title', 'imgPdfError');`.

Comment: Thank you I can see how I will do it now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Wrong way, should be:

```
function ValidatePdf() {
    if (!ValidateFields('txt_pdf_title', 'imgPdfError')) {
        // alert('not valid');
    }
}
```